# Adding to an excel file using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

I've written a code that will allow the user to enter data into the program and this will transfer to an excel file. However I dont want anything being added when one of my text boxes is empty.With this code a row is still being added despite my if else conditions.I have debugged and used break points and the txt_LRU != null is true even if txt_LRU is empty or not.Can someone please tell me why this is happening?

```
private void button_kaydet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

    //the text that is obtained from the text boxes and combo boxes.

    string txt_LRU = this.txtbx_LRUno.Text.ToString();
    string txt_yi = this.txtbx_yi.Text.ToString();
    string txt_td = this.cmbx_td.Text.ToString();
    string txt_toptarih = this.dtp_toplanti.Text.ToString();
    string txt_bastarih = this.dtp_bas.Text.ToString();
    string txt_teslimtarih = this.dtp_teslim.Text.ToString();
    string txt_ilgilinot = this.txtbx_ilgiliNot.Text.ToString();
    string txt_acikislem = this.txtbx_acikislem.Text.ToString();
    string txt_referedosya = this.txtbx_referedosya.Text.ToString();
    string txt_parcano = this.txtbx_parcano2.Text.ToString();

    int lru_row = 0;
    int kontrol = 0;




        //if there is non existing LRU then save the data into a new row in excel
        if (kontrol == 0)
        {
            if (txt_LRU != null || txt_LRU!="")
            {

                int x = satir_sayisi + 1;
                string satir_no = x.ToString();
                sheet1.Cells[1][satir_sayisi + 2] = satir_no;
                sheet1.Cells[2][satir_sayisi + 2] = txt_LRU;
                sheet1.Cells[3][satir_sayisi + 2] = txt_parcano;
                sheet1.Cells[4][satir_sayisi + 2] = txt_yi;
                sheet1.Cells[5][satir_sayisi + 2] = txt_acikislem;
                sheet1.Cells[7][satir_sayisi + 2] = txt_td;
                sheet1.Cells[8][satir_sayisi + 2] = txt_toptarih;
                sheet1.Cells[9][satir_sayisi + 2] = txt_bastarih;
                sheet1.Cells[10][satir_sayisi + 2] = txt_teslimtarih;
                sheet1.Cells[11][satir_sayisi + 2] = txt_ilgilinot;

            }   

            else if (txt_LRU == null || txt_LRU == "") 
                MessageBox.Show("Please add the LRU number "); 
            }


     //to save and close the excel file
    uyg.DisplayAlerts = false;
    kitap.Save();
    kitap.Close();
    uyg.DisplayAlerts = true;
    uyg.Quit();

   DialogResult dialogResult2 = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to see the excel file?", "Bilgilendirme", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (dialogResult2 == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        Process.Start(@"C:\\Users\\casperpc\\Desktop\\hey.xls");

    }
    else if (dialogResult2 == DialogResult.No)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This condition says that you will do stuff when your `txt_LRU` is not null, or is not empty.
When `txt_LRU` is `null` is not equals to an empty string. This case fulfill the `OR` condition.

```
 if (txt_LRU != null || txt_LRU!="")
            { 
/*row added*/
     }
```

The correct condition is `Not null AND not empty`:

```
 if (txt_LRU != null && txt_LRU!="")
            { 
/*row added*/
     }
```

PS: try using `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_LRU)`

Comment: you're welcome... Also, the else condition is the same as the IF condition, check that up.

Answer (score 1):

**Not for points.**

`Null` is not the same as a zero-length string. A simple check can give this info for you.

[image]

Code above is simply:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string txt_string = this.textBox1.Text.ToString();
    if (txt_string == null)
        MessageBox.Show("Yes");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("No");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a value to txt_LRU when you read from the text box. However, strings can only be null if they are not initialized. That is why you receive true.

See [this explanation](http://www.dotnetperls.com/null-string).